# map insertions replaces previously entered values

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I'm trying to code a container for a user-defined class. I read the key from a file and construct and insert the element in a map.but when I do so  in a loop, the elements are present but they all point to the same object...

as you will see in the code, I create a "Capture" that reads from a file to instanciate "Flux"es and store them in a map.
The issue is that within the loop, the insrted {key,value}replaces the previous values: keys remain but now point to the same object..

here comes my .h file:

```cpp
class Flux;

class Capture
{
public:
    Capture(pcpp::PcapLiveDevice* dev, std::string pcap_prefix, unsigned int max_pcap_size = 0);
    ~Capture();

private:
    std::map<std::string,Flux&> m_list_flux;
};

class Flux
{
public:
    Flux(std::string filter,std::string folder, std::string prefix, unsigned int max_pcap_size);
    ~Flux();

    void print();

private:
    std::string m_folder;
};
```

and here is my .cpp:

```cpp
Capture::Capture(pcpp::PcapLiveDevice * dev, std::string pcap_prefix, unsigned int max_pcap_size) 
{
    std::ifstream conf("flux.conf");
    std::string line;
    if (conf) {
        std::vector<std::string> cont;
        while (getline(conf, line)) {
            boost::split(cont, line, boost::is_any_of(":"));
            std::cout << "creating directory and flux: " << cont.back() << std::endl;
            fs::create_directory(cont.front());
            Flux flux(cont.back(), cont.front(), pcap_prefix, max_pcap_size);
            m_list_flux.emplace(cont.back(), flux);  //here the inserted flux replaces the previous one: the key remains intact but the value is changed: i have several keys pointing to the same object...
        }
        fs::create_directory("flux0");
        Flux flux2("any", "flux0", pcap_prefix, max_pcap_size);
        m_list_flux.emplace("any", flux2); // same here
    }

for (auto&it : m_list_flux) {
        std::cout << "launching flux: " << it.first << std::endl;
        it.second.print();
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
launching flux: 10.10.10.10
flux0
launching flux: 10.10.10.102
flux0
launching flux: any
flux0
```

I've tried to do it manually :

```cpp
Capture::Capture(pcpp::PcapLiveDevice * dev, std::string pcap_prefix, unsigned int max_pcap_size) 
{
    Flux flux("10.10.10.10", "flux1", m_pcap_prefix, max_pcap_size);
    m_list_flux.emplace("flux1", flux);
    Flux test("10.10.10.102", "flux2", m_pcap_prefix, max_pcap_size);
    m_list_flux.emplace("flux2", test);
    Flux test2("any", "flux0", m_pcap_prefix, max_pcap_size);
    m_list_flux.emplace("flux0", test2);

    for (auto&it : m_list_flux) {
        std::cout << "launching flux: " << it.first << std::endl;
        it.second.print();
    }
}
```

and it works fine in that case: it prints:

```
launching flux: 10.10.10.10
flux1
launching flux: 10.10.10.102
flux2
launching flux: any
flux0
```

my conf file only contains:

```
flux1:10.10.10.10
flux2:10.10.10.102
```

I'm probably missing something obvious but I'm far from being an expert so any help is appreciated.
Can someone explain to me this behavior? I just want my map to contain the different flux described in my configuration file.

Comment: `std::map<std::string,Flux&>` - what made you set the map's mapped type as `Flux&`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Flux flux(cont.back(), cont.front(), pcap_prefix, max_pcap_size);
m_list_flux.emplace(cont.back(), flux);
```

You've commented on the second line:

> here the inserted flux replaces the previous one: the key remains intact but the value is changed: i have several keys pointing to the same object...

You're lucky (unlucky?) that this works at all. You're storing references to temporary `Flux` objects created in that function. Change the type of your `map` to actually store them, and you'll fix your issue.